# Workflow date/time criteria

Tags: workflow, formula, datetime, criteria

I have a date/time field that store when an email was sent. I then want to have a workflow that resets another field on the record the next time the record is edited AND it is within a certain time period relative to the date/time in the field.

How can I set a workflow to fire if a record's date/time field value is >= 2hours ago?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple really: 
create a formula field to store the difference between the date/time and now
e.g., formula: Field_A__c - now()
Then create the workflow that use this value as its criteria.